# How to hide the back button inside the bottom Tab Bar Menu in Home Page. - ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

[image]I am trying to just hide the back button in Tab-Bar in my tab-home-page.html in ionic 4. 
I have try to hide the back button, but it will hide it for the other pages. 
and I have search through there, but can't find any.

Is there a way to get this done? Below is my Tab.page.HTML. Hope that some one would guide me in this.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button ion-button (click)="goBack()">
       <ion-icon name="arrow-undo-circle-sharp" class="img-size"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab-home">
      <ion-icon name="home-sharp" class="img-size"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab-profile">
      <ion-icon name="link-sharp" class="img-size"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>   
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

** edit **
to navigate back to ur home page , 
just add `<ion-back-button></ion-back-button>` to ur header inside ur navigated page

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

this will solve ur problem of not adding a tab button for ur back page.

Comment: I think you miss understand  my question, I have a tab bar at the bottom of every page in my. I wanted hid the back button on the home page.

Comment: can i ask why are using ur back button on ur tab bar ? u can use 
<ion-back-button> inside  the header of every page u require

Comment: is a user requirement to have the back button, to be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: u can put a *ngif and put a boolean condition on the respective button when set it to false on pages u don't require and true on which u require, simple show and hide

Comment: Do you have some example for me how to put a ngif?

Comment: i never had a requirement of using*ngIf inside a toolbar , but i can help , can u create a minimum repo on git or stackblitz or any other code sharing site i will help u out their ?